# How to use local python library

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I've written a python script that uses [steampy](https://github.com/bukson/steampy).
To that library I cloned it to a local folder, but now I don't know how to make my script use the local library instead of the installed one.

I'm coming from Angular where this is achievable by making a link with `npm link` between the two libraries.

Also, in my local [steampy](https://github.com/bukson/steampy) all imports referring to steampy error out, for example:
`from steampy.exceptions import ApiException, ...`

> No name 'exceptions' in module 'steampy.exceptions' pylint(no-name-in-module)
> Unable to import 'steampy.exceptions' pylint(import-error)`
> [image]

Comment: Are you working in a virtualenv?

Comment: A common way to do this is to create and activate a virtual environment. Then you can go into your steampy directory and run `python setup.py develop`. Depending on what this project's setup.py does, you may have to do `python setup.py install --force` every time you update the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are working in a virtualenv, you can just try:

```
pip install -e <path to the lib>
```

The `-e` flag makes the install editable, this means that if you do changes on the `steampy` repo, those will be available on the virtualenv.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put the steampy folder in the same directory as your script.

```
steampy
main.py
```